# What is "cite"?

Tags: discussion, citation

I see cite option under the questions. I want to know that what is the function of that cite button? Actually what is it for?
Any answer to this question is welcomed and will be appreciated by me.

Answer (score 18):

In [(La)TeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) you can manage your references using [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/) (see also [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management)). The code displayed with the cite is the code you would insert into your BibTeX file to get the proper formatting when referencing a MSE post. It is also possible to the use [amsrefs](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amsrefs) package with LaTeX, and you can have this code snippet displayed as well,